# PropelParamConverter not working

Tags: symfony, propel

Can someone please tell me how to make PropelParamConverter work for a Symfony2 project?
I already have the 'SensioFrameworkExtraBundle' bundle installed and working for the implicit case (without the annotation above the controller).
But using this code :

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="AcmeBundle:User", options={"mapping"={"username":"username"}})
 * @ParamConverter("gallery", class="AcmeBundle:Gallery", options={"mapping"={"id":"id"}})
 */
public function showAction(User $user, Gallery $gallery)
{
     ...
}
```

I get the following exception:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter" in method Acme\AcmeBundle\Controller\Frontend\GalleryController::showAction() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

The exception seems to be thrown inside Doctrine code (DocParse object), and this is surprising me because the DoctrineBundle is not even activated in my AppKernel!

Please tell me if I missed something in my Symfony2/Propel/FrameworkExtra configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ParamConverter which comes with the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle doesn't support Propel, there is only a Doctrine - and DataTime ParamConverter.

If you installed the [PropelBundle](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle) (which you should if you work with Propel), it will come with a Propel ParamConverter. See [the documentation](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/blob/1.1/Resources/doc/param_converter.markdown) how you can use it.

Comment: Yeah sure, but in fact the PropelParamConverter is never called and the execution still runs into Doctrine's code...
Is there some additional DI configuration to be made to make the Annotation use the Propel ParamConverter?